# How to get check_mk BI aggregation status when tab is collapsed in tree?

Tags: nagios, check-mk

Check_mk provides the script check_bi_local.py to make a nagios check from the status of the BI tool. The issue is that this only returns the elements of the view that are expanded in the tree. Is there a way to get the status of elements that are collapsed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that there are a couple ways of doing this. One is to define aggregations from rules in your main tree. You can copy/paste the arguments and rules but you have to make sure they're the same. This clutters your all aggregations view, but it works.

The other way you must modify the source code. Just edit the execute_tree function in bi.py to print the results to file, and you can grab it from there.